# Реализация почленного сложения матриц (двумерных векторов) в классе (ООП)

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, матрицы

Пытаюсь написать класс Матриц для реализации сложения, умножения на число и т.д. Чтобы сделать это, надо найти баг в коде (конкретнее в сложении). Лучше сложение матриц вообще переписать, т.к. у меня коряво получилось.

```
   class Matrix:
      def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body

      def __add__(self, matr):
        for i in zip(self.body, self.matr):
          lst = []
          for j in zip(i): 
            result.append = sum(j)
        c.append(lst)
        return Matrix(c)


    m0 = Matrix([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
    m1 = Matrix([[9,8,7], [6,5,4], [3,2,1]])
    print(m1 + m0)
```

Интерпретатор выдает следующие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 16, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in __add__
AttributeError: 'Matrix' object has no attribute 'matr'
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может стоит воспользоваться Numpy или вам исключительно в образовательных целях?

Answer (score 2):

Вот в этой строчке:

```
for i in zip(self.body, self.matr):
```

у вас никакого `self.matr` не существует. У вас есть просто `matr`

PS: читайте сообщения об ошибках - это сэкономит вам кучу времени и нервов. Вам же интерпретатор прямым текстом написал, в какой строке у вас ошибка и в чём она заключается.